# Question about actions of full transformation monoids

Tags: semigroups, monoid

Consider a monoid $M$ acting on a set $X$, where $M$ is the full transformation monoid on some set $A$.

Say that $B\subseteq A$ *fixes* $x\in X$ iff, for all $m\in M$, if $m(b) = b$ for all $b\in B$, then $mx=x$.

Say that $B\subseteq A$ *pins down* $x\in X$ iff, for all $m,n\in M$, if $m(b)=n(b)$ for all $b\in B$, then $mx=nx$.

Question 1: If $B$ fixes $x$, does it follow that $B$ pins down $x$?

Question 2: If $B$ and $B'$ both pin down $x$, does it follow that $B\cap B'$ pins down $x$?

Comment: The answers to both questions are "yes" https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289750/question-about-actions-of-full-transformation-monoids